# Игнорирование переноса на новую строку при чтении из файла (Perl)

Tags: файлы, строки, perl

Как в Perl'e игнорировать перенос на новую строку при чтении из файла?

К примеру, данная программа считает текст из файлов, которые подаём через командную строку в виде аргументов, и распечатает этот текст. Но он прочтёт только первую строку каждого из файлов.

Как видоизменить код, чтобы он читал весь файл?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use warnings;

my @names_of_files = @ARGV;
for my $i (0..$#names_of_files){
   open( my $input_data, '<', $names_of_files[$i] );
   my @words = split(" ", <$input_data>);
   print @words, "\n";
   close ( $input_data );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Самый простой способ - это перед открытием файла написать такое

```
local $/=undef;
```

local там нужен, что бы не вышло за пределы блока (Вам же не хочется, что бы во всей программе поменялось поведение?)

Comment: Ого! Вот это да! Не могли бы Вы, если не сложно, что конкретно делает эта строка?

Comment: описано здесь http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html
если кратко, то она выставляет признак конца строки в undef и получается, что теперь все содержимое файла - одна строка. Кстати, можно его в пробел выставить, тогда построчное чтение будет приводить к чтению "по словам". Но там могут быть сюрпризы.

Answer (score 0):

А оно вам надо - читать весь файл в память? Достаточно этого:

```
while( <$input_data> ) {
    chomp; print;
}
```

> Как в Perl'e игнорировать новую строку при чтении из файла?

См. [chomp](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html). Если нужен аналог trim(), то:

```
s/^\s+|\s+$//gs;
```

Если нужно пропускать пустые строки, то:

```
chomp; print if $_;
```

А можно заменять переводы строк на пробелы, но это уже самостоятельно :)

P.S. И присвоение тоже лишнее:

```
my @names_of_files = @ARGV;
```

Ничто не мешает итерировать `@ARGV`.